# Creating User twice in sql server for new registration

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, user-registration

I'm trying to create a new user and everything works fine but it enters the same records twice to my db. I have already tried to kept some breakpoints but couldn't find where am I going wrong.

This is my Registration.aspx code:

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim msg As MailMessage
    Dim UserID As String

    Dim ActivationUrl As String = String.Empty
    Dim emailId As String = String.Empty
    UserID = Guid.NewGuid.ToString


    'Create ConnectionString and Inser Statement
    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim insertSql As String = "INSERT INTO Users (UserID,UserName,Password,Email,Mobile,Address,CreatedDate)" & " values (@UserID,@UserName,@Password,@Email,@Mobile,@Address,@CreatedDate)"
    'Create SQL connection
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

    'Create SQL Command And Sql Parameters

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(insertSql, con)


    Dim usernumber As New SqlParameter()
    usernumber.ParameterName = "@UserID"
    usernumber.Value = UserID
    cmd.Parameters.Add(usernumber)

    Dim username As New SqlParameter()
    username.ParameterName = "@Username"
    username.Value = txtUserName.Text.ToString()
    cmd.Parameters.Add(username)

    Dim password As New SqlParameter()
    password.ParameterName = "@Password"
    password.Value = txtPassword.Text.ToString()
    cmd.Parameters.Add(password)

    Dim email As New SqlParameter()
    email.ParameterName = "@Email"
    email.Value = txtEmail.Text.ToString()
    cmd.Parameters.Add(email)

    Dim mobile As New SqlParameter()
    mobile.ParameterName = "@Mobile"
    mobile.Value = txtMobile.Text.ToString()
    cmd.Parameters.Add(mobile)

    Dim address As New SqlParameter()
    address.ParameterName = "@Address"
    address.Value = txtAddress.Text.ToString()
    cmd.Parameters.Add(address)

    Dim createddate As New SqlParameter()
    createddate.ParameterName = "@CreatedDate"
    createddate.Value = Date.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
    cmd.Parameters.Add(createddate)


    Try
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        lblMsg.Text = "User Registration successful"
    Catch ex As SqlException
        Dim errorMessage As String = "Error in registering user"
        errorMessage += ex.Message

        Throw New Exception(errorMessage)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try


    Try
        'Sending activation link in the email
        msg = New MailMessage()
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient()
        emailId = txtEmail.Text.Trim()
        'sender email address
        msg.From = New MailAddress("voletykiran@gmail.com")
        'Receiver email address
        msg.[To].Add(emailId)
        msg.Subject = "Confirmation email for account activation"
        'For testing replace the local host path with your lost host path and while making online replace with your website domain name
        ActivationUrl = Server.HtmlEncode("http://localhost:8769/UserRegistration/ActivateAccount.aspx?UserID=" & FetchUserId(emailId) & "&Email=" & emailId)

        msg.Body = "Hi " & txtUserName.Text.Trim() & "!" & vbLf & "Thanks for showing interest and registring in <a href='http://www.webcodeexpert.com'> webcodeexpert.com<a> " & " Please <a href='" & ActivationUrl & "'>click here to activate</a>  your account and enjoy our services. " & vbLf & "Thanks!"
        msg.IsBodyHtml = True
        smtp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("voletykiran@gmail.com", "india@1a")
        smtp.Port = 587
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        smtp.EnableSsl = True
        smtp.Send(msg)
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "Message", "alert('Confirmation Link to activate account has been sent  to your email address');", True)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "Message", "alert('Error occured : " & ex.Message.ToString() & "');", True)
        Return
    Finally
        ActivationUrl = String.Empty
        emailId = String.Empty
        con.Close()

    End Try
End Sub

Private Function FetchUserId(emailId As String) As String
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
    cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT UserID FROM users WHERE Email=@Email", con)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", emailId)
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        con.Open()
    End If
    Dim UserID As String = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    con.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
    Return UserID
End Function

Private Sub clear_controls()
    txtUserName.Text = String.Empty
    txtPassword.Text = String.Empty
    txtConfirmPassword.Text = String.Empty
    txtEmail.Text = String.Empty
    txtMobile.Text = String.Empty
    txtAddress.Text = String.Empty
    txtUserName.Focus()
End Sub
```

Can anyone say me where am I misleading?

Comment: @SearchAndResQ-This is how I'm calling Dim insertSql As String = "INSERT INTO Users (UserID,UserName,Password,Email,Mobile,Address,CreatedDate)" & " values (@UserID,@UserName,@Password,@Email,@Mobile,@Address,@CreatedDate)"

Comment: Updated.Please check

Comment: Are you using Update_Panel on your aspx page? Somehow your page is calling the same event twice. Can you please also post your aspx page and page_load function?

Comment: I'm curious if you have an `onclick` property in your button's tag referencing the subroutine in addition to having a handler on the subroutine for that specific button. If you do both it'll fire the subroutine twice, once for each of those. Just throwing that out there because that happened to me a couple of times.